What movie is this GIF from?
I'm attempting to identify what film this scene is from. I found the image in a gallery of random GIFs and all the description said was "Scary movie".
I don't recognize the actress or the man in the photograph, but judging from the electrical outlet on the wall it appears to be either French or Russian. The location is definitely in an EU country, but France, Germany and Russia all have similar wall outlets.
So, judging from the wall outlet AND the FX on the ghost/monster, I'm looking for a European horror film from the last 10 years or so.

I've done google searches for several combinations of "ghost", "framed photo", "reflection", "french", "russian", "redhead", etc. but I'm not finding anything useful so far.

Do you have any other information about this? Where do you have that GIF from? What does the source you got it from say about it? Do you even know that it actually is from a movie/TV-show at all and not just some random internet stuff?

@NapoleonWilson - the source was a collection of random animated GIFs, and all it said for this one was "Scary movie". I updated the answer to include that. At any rate, I have my answer - it was a short film on YouTube.

See you soon, a 14 second horror film




Excellent, and fast too. Did you already know it or did you just find it quickly?

@Omegacron, I saw it on this site, here is the film
